# Excel formula to sum unique values of 5 columns?

Tags: excel

Basically I have 7 columns in my table like this -

[image]

and I want it like this

[image]

Sum of column F and average of column G for unique value of column A+B+C+D+E.
I have great no of records>10000 so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use a pivot table for this

Comment: @TimWilliams I used pivot table but it ives row by row, i want a table like structure.

Answer (score 0):

TDLR : use sumif()

Assuming your '7 columns' data is located at `A2:G6` , and the 2nd unique value table is located at `A8:E10` .

in `F8` put

```
=SUMIFS(F$2:F$6,$A$2:$A$6,$A8,$B$2:$B$6,$B8,$C$2:$C$6,$C8,$D$2:$D$6,$D8,$E$2:$E$6,$E8)
```

the drag to `G10` . Have a try.. do share if you get stuck. ( :